# Moving $http.post call into a service

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS not stupid, LOL. I had this call in a controller, I wanted to move it to a service. I need to make it available to multiple controllers.

```
 $http.post("/admin/Leads/LoadLeads.ashx", dataObj)
    .success(function (response) {
        $scope.Leads = response.p;
    });
```

Here is what I have tried. Getting back a response cant assign the data the same way.

**Service:**

```
myLeadDashboard.factory('LeadsServiceTest',[function(){
            return {
                retrievePostData: function($http,dataObj){
                    return $http.post("/admin/Leads/LoadLeads.ashx", dataObj);
                    }
            }
        }]);
```

**Controller:**

```
 var LeadsPromise = LeadsServiceTest.retrievePostData($http,dataObj);
            LeadsPromise.then(function(data) {
                $scope.Leads = data.p;
            });
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I not Understanding? If you need more information about what I am doing please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HttpPromise.sucess spreads the response object so that the first parameter is the data...$q.then gives you the raw response object. You can access the data from your controller with the following:

```
 var LeadsPromise = LeadsServiceTest.retrievePostData($http,dataObj);
 LeadsPromise.then(function(response) {
   $scope.Leads = response.data.p;
 });
```

Comment: It's good to get used to this now, too. `$http` has deprecated the success/error handlers: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice

Comment: So does $q inherit $http? As it would look from OOP standards ?

Comment: The $http functions return a custom $q promise that provides the additional success/error functions...since they're deprecating them you should stick with using the result of $http calls as a standard $q promise. If you want your service function to return the actual data, you could use promise chaining: `return $http.post(...).then(function(response){return response.data;});`

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I like to use angular services -

```
.service('mySpecialService', [
        '$q',
        'Restangular',
        function MyService($q, Restangular) {


            MyService.prototype.list = function() {
                return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                    //make list call
                });
            };

            MyService.prototype.post = function(data) {
                return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                   //make post call
                });
            };

            MyService.prototype.delete = function(id) {

                return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                    //delete by id
                });
            };

            MyService.prototype.list = function list() {

                return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                   //make list call
                });
            };
```

So I like to use `$q`, and also `restangular` in place of `$http` - but `$http` is fine if you like that. Then you inject the service where ever you mean to use it and call it!

So like - in a controller where you have it injected it could be like

```
 MyService.post(postData);
```

and because I use `$q` you have the options of using the promises like

```
  MyService.post(postData)
      .then(function(data){
        //call complete logic
      })
      .catch(function(err){
          console.log("error in post ", err);
      });
```

Just note - if you don't use `$q`, you will have a `.data` layer.

Comment: Is the $q property's sole purpose error handling ? My API handles most of that. By the time it hits my frontend code it just needs to render in appropriate places. And expose calls back to my API to update the database appropriately. Angular seems like a great way of doing this. The learning curve is a slight weight though.

Comment: @kcbeard not purely no, it is a promise library that will just catch if anything errors out on you

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your Service, you have to put the **$http** service as parameter of your service function. Then, **$http** service return promise.

When you use **.then()**, it returns a promise while **.success()** is more traditional way of registering callbacks and doesn't return a promise.

PS : a good tips is to wrap your services/controllers/etc.. declaration into anonymous function.

You can do the following :

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, Service) {

  //Retrieve our promise
  var promise = Service.post([1,2,3]);

  promise.then(function(response){
    //Retrieve our data
    console.log(response.data);
  });

  promise.success(function(data){
    //Data is what i want, it is not raw data
    console.log(data)
  });

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

**Service**

```
(function(){

  function Service($http){


    function post(data){
      //Return promise
      return $http.post('path_to_url', data);
    }

    var factory = {
      post: post
    };

    return factory;

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Service', Service);

})();
```